How to load 3D models in Django
This is the main.js file that i have for a website that i just made:
// Import necessary Three.js modules
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from './libs/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from './libs/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';

// Get the container element for the 3D model
const modelContainer = document.getElementById('model-container');

// Create a WebGL renderer with transparency and anti-aliasing
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ 
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
});
renderer.outputColorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;

// Function to handle renderer resize
function updateRendererSize() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
updateRendererSize();

// Configure renderer settings
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

modelContainer.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = null;

// Lighting setup
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
scene.add(ambientLight);

const directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
directionalLight1.position.set(5, 5, 5);
directionalLight1.castShadow = true;
scene.add(directionalLight1);

const directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffd700, 1);
directionalLight2.position.set(-5, 3, -5);
scene.add(directionalLight2);

const frontLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
frontLight.position.set(0, 0, 5);
scene.add(frontLight);

const pointLight1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xff9000, 1, 10);
pointLight1.position.set(2, 2, 2);
scene.add(pointLight1);

const pointLight2 = new THREE.PointLight(0x0066ff, 1, 10);
pointLight2.position.set(-2, 2, -2);
scene.add(pointLight2);

// Camera setup
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(4, 5, 11);

// Controls setup
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.enablePan = false;
controls.minDistance = 5;
controls.maxDistance = 20;
controls.minPolarAngle = 0.5;
controls.maxPolarAngle = 1.5;
controls.autoRotate = false;
controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
controls.enabled = false;
controls.update();

// Variables for model interaction
let modelMesh;
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
const targetRotation = new THREE.Vector2();
const currentRotation = new THREE.Vector2();
const smoothness = 0.1;
let clock = new THREE.Clock();
let isMobile = window.innerWidth <= 768;

// Check if device is mobile
function checkMobile() {
    return window.innerWidth <= 768;
}

// Mouse move handler
function onMouseMove(event) {
    if (!isMobile) {
        mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 - 1;
        
        targetRotation.x = -mouse.y * 0.5;
        targetRotation.y = mouse.x * 0.5;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

// Load the 3D model
const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath('public/model/');
loader.load('scene.gltf', 
    (gltf) => {
        console.log('loading model');
        modelMesh = gltf.scene;

        modelMesh.traverse((child) => {
            if (child.isMesh) {
                child.castShadow = true;
                child.receiveShadow = true;
                
                if (child.material) {
                    child.material.transparent = false;
                    child.material.opacity = 1;
                    child.material.depthWrite = true;
                    child.material.depthTest = true;
                    child.material.metalness = 0.7;
                    child.material.roughness = 0.3;
                    child.material.color = new THREE.Color(0xcccccc);
                    child.material.envMapIntensity = 1.5;
                    child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                }
            }
        });

        // Adjust scale based on device
        const scale = isMobile ? 20 : 30;
        modelMesh.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
        
        // Center the model
        modelMesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);

        scene.add(modelMesh);

        const pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(renderer);
        pmremGenerator.compileEquirectangularShader();
        
        const environmentTexture = pmremGenerator.fromScene(new THREE.Scene()).texture;
        scene.environment = environmentTexture;

        // Adjust camera position based on device
        if (isMobile) {
            camera.position.set(0, 4, 12);
        } else {
            camera.position.set(8, 4, 8);
        }
        controls.update();

        document.getElementById('progress-container').style.display = 'none';
    },
    (xhr) => {
        console.log(`loading ${xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100}%`);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.error(error);
    }
);

// Animation loop
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    
    if (modelMesh) {
        if (isMobile) {
            // Floating animation for mobile
            const time = clock.getElapsedTime();
            modelMesh.position.y = Math.sin(time) * 0.3;
            modelMesh.rotation.y = time * 0.2;
        } else {
            // Mouse-based animation for desktop
            currentRotation.x += (targetRotation.x - currentRotation.x) * smoothness;
            currentRotation.y += (targetRotation.y - currentRotation.y) * smoothness;
            
            modelMesh.rotation.x = currentRotation.x;
            modelMesh.rotation.y = currentRotation.y;
        }
    }
    
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// Handle window resize
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    isMobile = checkMobile();
    updateRendererSize();
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    
    // Update camera position on resize
    if (modelMesh) {
        if (isMobile) {
            camera.position.set(0, 4, 12);
            modelMesh.scale.set(20, 20, 20);
            modelMesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            camera.position.set(8, 4, 8);
            modelMesh.scale.set(30, 30, 30);
            modelMesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    
    controls.update();
});

animate();

Here is the index.html for it:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Elegance Studio</title>
    <script async src="./libs/es-module-shims.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">

    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
            "three": "./libs/three.module.js",
            "three/addons/": "./libs/addons/"
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, #002642, #111111);
            color: #F2F2F2;
            min-height: 100vh;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        #model-container {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        .container {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            padding: 1rem;
        }

        .hero-content {
            backdrop-filter: blur(1px) saturate(180%);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
            background-color: rgba(0, 38, 66, 0.2);
            border-radius: 12px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(204, 255, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 1.5rem;
            margin: 1rem;
            margin-top: 70px;
            max-width: 800px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: clamp(2rem, 5vw, 3rem);
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
            background: linear-gradient(45deg, #CCFF00, #F2F2F2);
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .subtitle {
            font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 1.2rem);
            margin-bottom: 2rem;
            color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.8);
            text-align: center;
        }

        .specs {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(120px, 1fr));
            gap: 1rem;
            margin-bottom: 2rem;
        }

        .spec-item {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 1rem;
            backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
            background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);
            border-radius: 8px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(204, 255, 0, 0.2);
        }

        .cards-section {
            padding: 1rem;
            margin: 1rem;
        }

        h2 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 2rem;
            font-size: clamp(2rem, 4vw, 2.5rem);
            background: linear-gradient(45deg, #CCFF00, #F2F2F2);
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        }

        .cards-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
            gap: 1.5rem;
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0 1rem;
        }

        .card {
            backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
            background-color: rgba(0, 38, 66, 0.3);
            border-radius: 12px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(204, 255, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 1.5rem;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease;
        }

        .card:hover {
            transform: translateY(-5px);
        }

        .about-section {
            padding: 2rem 1rem;
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .about-content {
            backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
            background-color: rgba(0, 38, 66, 0.3);
            border-radius: 12px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(204, 255, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 1.5rem;
            margin: 1rem 0;
        }

        .about-grid {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(280px, 1fr));
            gap: 1.5rem;
            margin-top: 2rem;
        }

        .contact-section {
            padding: 2rem 1rem;
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .contact-container {
            backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
            background-color: rgba(0, 38, 66, 0.3);
            border-radius: 12px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(204, 255, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 1.5rem;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .social-icons {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            gap: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
            margin-top: 2rem;
        }

        .social-icons a {
            color: #F2F2F2;
            font-size: clamp(1.5rem, 4vw, 2rem);
            transition: transform 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
        }

        .header {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 1rem;
            background: rgba(0, 38, 66, 0.9);
            backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
            z-index: 100;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .navbar {
            display: flex;
            gap: 1rem;
        }

        .navbar a {
            color: #F2F2F2;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
            transition: color 0.3s ease;
        }

        .navbar a:hover {
            color: #CCFF00;
        }

        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            .container {
                padding: 0.5rem;
            }

            .hero-content {
                margin: 0.5rem;
                padding: 1rem;
                margin-top: 60px;
            }

            .specs {
                grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
            }

            .cards-section {
                padding: 0.5rem;
                margin: 0.5rem;
            }

            .navbar {
                display: none;
            }

            .header {
                padding: 0.5rem;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 480px) {
            .spec-item {
                padding: 0.8rem;
            }

            .social-icons {
                gap: 1rem;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Existing header -->
    <header class="header">
        <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>

        <i class='bx bx-menu' id="menu-icon"></i>

        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- Existing model container -->
    <div id="model-container">
        <div id="progress-container">
            <div id="progress"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Existing container -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hero-content">
            <h1>Elegance Studio DMV</h1>
            <p class="subtitle">Capturing Moments, Crafting Memories</p>
            <div class="specs">
                <div class="spec-item">
                    <h3>Creativity</h3>
                    <p>Artistic Vision</p>
                </div>
                <div class="spec-item">
                    <h3>Quality</h3>
                    <p>High Resolution</p>
                </div>
                <div class="spec-item">
                    <h3>Timeless</h3>
                    <p>Lasting Captures</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <button class="cta-button">Learn More</button> -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Existing cards section -->
    <div class="cards-section">
        <h2>Expertise</h2>
        <div class="cards-container">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Creative Vision</h3>
                <p>Our artistry knows no bounds. We bring a unique touch to every shoot, ensuring each photograph tells
                    a captivating story.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Technical Mastery</h3>
                <p>Equipped with high-end cameras and advanced editing tools, we transform ordinary shots into stunning
                    visuals.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Professional Experience</h3>
                <p>With years of experience, our seasoned photographers deliver exceptional results, consistently
                    exceeding client expectations.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Adaptability</h3>
                <p>Whether it's a landscape or portrait, we tailor our approach to fit your vision, ensuring perfect
                    results in any setting.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- New About Section -->
    <section class="about-section">
        <h2>About Us</h2>
        <div class="about-content">
            <div class="about-grid">
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>Our Story</h3>
                    <p>From our humble beginnings as passionate hobbyists, we've grown into a professional photography
                        brand. Our journey is marked by significant milestones that reflect our dedication and love for
                        the craft, evolving with every step to bring you exceptional photography.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>Our Mission</h3>
                    <p>We strive to capture the true essence of each moment, immortalizing emotions through our lens.
                        Our mission is to continuously innovate, pushing the boundaries of traditional photography to
                        deliver images that resonate deeply with our clients.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>Our Approach</h3>
                    <p>We center our process around you. Your needs and vision guide every project we undertake,
                        ensuring a personalized experience. With meticulous attention to detail, from the initial
                        concept to the final edit, we guarantee photographs that are as unique as you are.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- New Contact Section -->
    <section class="contact-section">
        
        <div class="contact-container">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <div class="social-icons">
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Existing script import -->
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

So what i am trying to do is load this exact same website on a Django project.
I tried using the {% load static %} methods. i even tried putting the model in the media folder that i created.
what am i missing? the website loads, but the model does not.
here is the project structure for the website:
Elegant
│   index.html
│   main.js
│   portfolio.html
│   README.md
├───images
│       photo 1.jpg
├───libs
│   │   es-module-shims.js
│   │   three.module.js
│   └───addons
│       ├───controls
│       │       OrbitControls.js
│       ├───loaders
│       │       GLTFLoader.js
│       └───utils
│               BufferGeometryUtils.js
└───public
    │   index.css
    │   index2.css
    │   style.css
    ├───fonts
    │       SF Distant Galaxy.ttf
    └───model
        │   license.txt
        │   scene.bin
        │   scene.gltf
        └───textures
                CAM0001_Textures_baseColor.png
                CAM0001_Textures_metallicRoughness.png
                CAM0001_Textures_normal.png

So basically how do i get this project to work on a Django project. is there a specific file structure format that i have to follow? Any changes to the code that i have?

here is the Github repo where i have hosted the HTML/CSS/JS code: https://github.com/sudosu-sys/elegant.git
here is a live demo on netlify: https://from-nahom.netlify.app

Download the minified version of three js
Put it somewhere where your static sources have access to
Reference it in your code
https://github.com/sudosu-sys/elegant/blob/main/index.html#L12
https://discoverthreejs.com/book/introduction/get-threejs/
https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation

